# I get FatalExecutionEngineError when I am debugging unit test with Resharper on visual studio

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging, resharper-8.2

I keep getting this error message when I am trying to debug through my project. The same code works on colleges machine. I currently use Windows 8.1 and resharper 8.2 and after initial few methods within a selenium test. I am also using VMware workstation 10.0.4

FatalExecutionEngineError occurred

```
Message: Managed Debugging Assistant 'FatalExecutionEngineError' has detected a problem in    
'C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\ReSharper\v8.2\Bin\JetBrains.ReSharper.TaskRunner.CLR45.x64.exe'.

Additional information: The runtime has encountered a fatal error.
The address of the error was at 0x7d608056, on thread 0xfb8. The error code is 0xc0000005.
This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code.
Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke,
which may corrupt the stack.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with stopping the Re-Sharper plugin. If it start to work after disable of Re-Sharper from Visual Studio then uninstall and install re-sharper.

Answer (score 0):

When i turn off breaking on all exceptions in VS (Ctrl+Alt+E), debugging becames available.